# ¿Cómo consumir API de actualización de Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, webapi

Tengo un API hecha en c# netcore llamada "refreskToken" el cual recibe dos parámetros y me retorna un token nuevo, mis demás API están protegidas por Token Bearer (JWT). Cuando el token expira debo utilizar el API de refreskToken, pero, ¿cómo lo podría consumir?

`Token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs...."` ,
`RefreshToken = "84d7a036-f5d1-403c"`

Comment: si del lado del cliente el token ya expiro, solicitas un nuevo token enviando el token expirado y el tokenrefresh, si el token refresh aun es valido , el servidor te devuelve un nuevo token y un nuevo tokenrefresh

Answer (score -1):

Si estás en Web Api, utilizas el decorador `[Authorize]` para todas las Apis protegidas, sin embargo para consumir el refreshToken necesitas el decorador `[AllowAnonymous]` y con eso puedes consumirlo sin necesidad de que te solicite el token bearer.